# How does the SE(OpenData) site Graduate from the Beta phase?

Tags: discussion

How long and how does the StackExchange site Graduate from the Beta phase?
Does it depend on the number of visits or the number of questions per day?

Can OpenData SE graduate from the beta phase in the next couple of months or years?

Comment: here is a link to the stats: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51674/open-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of time that Open Data has been in Beta can be seen from the age of its first question: [Is there a list of all US Government agencies and sub agencies and is it available via API?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1) i.e. 8 years 6 months as of today.

[De-emphasising the beta designation by removing it from the banner on perpetual beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312773) assures us that the path out of Beta for older sites is being worked on.

Personally, I think the [Beta label should be removed as soon as a site has spent 7 years in Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331728/215590).  The significance of 7 years, rather than less or more, is that it has previously been used to remove the Beta labels from 29 other sites at [Congratulations to our 29 oldest beta sites - They're now no longer beta!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708)

Comment: Umm the site is dead, why move it out of Beta?

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 what makes you think it is dead?  My perception is the opposite and I was surprised to see that it still has a Beta label.

Comment: First and utmost, no active mods. Check them out, two of the three were seen over a month ago, one seen 22 days ago. That means not a single mod even visited for over 3 weeks. This fact alone (no active mods) means, in my opinion, a dead site, that rely on users from other sites to come and clean spam posts on it. If not for Smokey (and similar bots, if exists) the site main page would have been pile of spam.

Comment: Second, dead meta. One question is ALL 2021. No meta activity at all means none of the community members care about the community.

Comment: [Example of a live and kicking beta site](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Newest). Meta has lots of activity, only two mods but both are actually on the site, visiting, and doing what mods should be doing. This site (Open Data) is just very very far from there. Honestly, no idea why SE didn't shut it down yet.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 I like to see mods active, and to see some vibrancy in Meta, but as long as questions are being asked and answered on the Main site (https://opendata.stackexchange.com/?tab=active) I think Open Data has a future.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard: My optimistic point of view is that Open Data is one of the least controversial sites, and its topic is clear (everyone pretty much understands naturally whether a question is on-topic or off-topic).